# Dynamic config file generation using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to build a config file for a monitoring app for all our SQL Servers. For this I need to add all instance details of a server in a config file(i.e. one file will be generated per server and not instance). So even if server has multiple instances, it will only have one config file with its details of all instances mentioned in it. For a server with only single instance it is not a problem. What I need help is on a server with multiple instances. For e.g. If server1 has two instances Instance1 and 2 then config file should look  like below and exported to a text file. Likewise for a single instance server there will be only 1 line without comma at the end and exported to a text file.

```
"Server=Server1\Instance1;Port=50001;User ID:sqltest;password:****",
"Server=Server1\Instance2;Port=50002;User ID:sqltest;password:****"
```

I am getting all server instance details from a SQL Server database stored in format ServerName, InstanceName, PortName. Could someone please guide me how do I achieve it using Powershell? Thanks!

I have already tried something like below. But it has multiple issues like not getting correct port number, adding output to newline everytime there are multiple instances, not having comma for the last instance and generating file for each server rather than a each instance.

```
$serverlist = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT servername,instancename,portname from sqlmonitor" -ServerInstance "MainInstance"$textoutput = "This is a test."
Foreach {$server in $serverlist.servername}
{
    $textoutput += "`nServer=$Server;Port=$serverlist.portname;User ID:sqltest;password:****"}
$textoutput | Out-File "C:\temp\$server_config.txt"


Sample data from sqlmonitor table:

servername,instancename,portname
    server1,inst1,50001
    server2,inst1,50001
    server2,inst2,50002
```

I am still at an initial PS learning phase and know my code has lot of issues. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
# Create an array to hold some new objects
$arrServers = @()

# Run through your serverlist
foreach ($server in $serverlist.servername){
  # if it is a server you have already added to your new array, then just add the text to the output
  if ($arrServers.servername -contains $server ) {
    # There is probably an easier way to do this, but this just locates the position in the array where $server is found, then updates text for that location
    $arrServers[([array]::indexof($($arrServers.servername),$server))].textoutput += ",`nServer=$Server;Port=$serverlist.portname;User ID:sqltest;password:****"
  # otherwise create a new object to store your servername and textoutput
  } else {      
    $obj = New-Object System.Object
    Add-Member -InputObject $obj -NotePropertyName "servername" -NotePropertyValue $server
    Add-Member -InputObject $obj -NotePropertyName "textoutput" -NotePropertyValue "`nServer=$Server;Port=$serverlist.portname;User ID:sqltest;password:****"
    $arrServers += $obj
    $obj = $null
  }
}

# All done, so now we run out a file for each server
$arrServers | foreach {Out-File "C:\temp\$($_.servername)_config.txt}
```

Alternatively you could probably add in an `ORDER BY servername ASC` to your SQL so your server instances are grouped together then run a check on each loop to see if the current servername is the same as the previous before running out-file, but that seems clunkier.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Really appreciate it! Although, I didn't give the exact output I was looking for, it did help me in pointing me to the right direction.